# JSTL tag set/if

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

Evaluating using JSTL if

Why my value isOnline is not being evaluated as true using JSTL if

```
<c:set var="isOnline" value="${friend.online}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{isOnline}" />
<br/>
(isOnline) is: ${isOnline}
<c:if test="${isOnline == 'true'}" var="theTruth">
  <h:outputText value="hello"/>
</c:if>
<br/>
(isOnline == 'true') is: ${theTruth}
```

The result:

```
true
(isOnline) is: true
(isOnline == 'true') is: false
```

I am not really sure why the  condition is being evaluated as false even though i am printing the value of isOnline which shows it's true.

any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If it's a boolean, then you should not compare it to string. Just do

```
<c:if test="${isOnline}">
```

Further, I see that you're using JSF. You should really try to avoid JSTL tags as much as possible whenever JSF provides the same functionality out the box. That's because they doesn't run in sync as you'd expect from coding and may lead to unforeseen behaviour in certain circumstances. Just use the JSF `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="Hello" rendered="#{friend.online}" />
```

For more examples of using the `rendered` attribute, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993719/how-to-compare-2-strings-with-cif/4993776#4993776).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will probably use rendered as you recommended. Because i am getting strange behavior when using JSTL if. even though friend.online is boolean but still getting evaluated as false using <c:if test="#{friend.online}">
 and i am not sure why.

Comment: Then you're using this inside a `h:dataTable`. Use the `rendered` attribute instead. See also the linked answer.